# Creating a search bar that filters through nested details tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a search bar that filters through nested details tag elements.
I have a nested details tag like this:

```html
<div id="details-info">
  <details>
    <summary><a href="#" class="search">SD</a></summary>
        <p>
          <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
            <summary class="search">172.17.42.26 </summary>
                <p class="search">3033343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">3038373857383498</p>
                <p class="search">3647595959343498</p>
                <p class="search">374d343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">4253595959343498</p>
                <p class="search">4758343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">5139343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">5837553546353498</p>                  </details>
         </p>
         <p>
         <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
              <summary class="search">172.17.42.24 </summary>                   <p class="search">5336594e58343498</p>
                  <p class="search">56344f4330393498</p>
                  <p class="search">5a4a444133393498</p>              </details>
         </p>
   </details>
   <details>
      <summary><a href="#" class="search">HinduKush</a></summary>
      <p>
        <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
          <summary class="search">172.17.42.25 </summary>
          <p class="search">48314b4e58343498</p>
          <p class="search">4f32353857383498</p>
          <p class="search">4f58585959343498</p>
          <p class="search">56365a5959343498</p>
          </details></p></details>
</div>
```

I have a class name `search` for every Item I need to search. But, how do I loop through every tag and child nodes to filter? I need a search bar that autocompletes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to control the `display` of the child nodes depending on a search value?

Hope this will be helpful.

```js
const searchbar = document.getElementById('search-bar');
searchbar.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const searchKey = event.target.value;
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.search');
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    node.style.display = (node.textContent.indexOf(searchKey) > -1) ? 'block' : 'none';
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Enter the search key" />
<div id="details-info">
  <details>
    <summary><a href="#" class="search">SD</a></summary>
    <p>
      <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
        <summary class="search">172.17.42.26 </summary>
        <p class="search">3033343857383498</p>
        <p class="search">3038373857383498</p>
        <p class="search">3647595959343498</p>
        <p class="search">374d343857383498</p>
        <p class="search">4253595959343498</p>
        <p class="search">4758343857383498</p>
        <p class="search">5139343857383498</p>
        <p class="search">5837553546353498</p>
      </details>
    </p>
    <p>
      <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
        <summary class="search">172.17.42.24 </summary>
        <p class="search">5336594e58343498</p>
        <p class="search">56344f4330393498</p>
        <p class="search">5a4a444133393498</p>
      </details>
    </p>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary><a href="#" class="search">HinduKush</a></summary>
    <p>
      <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
        <summary class="search">172.17.42.25 </summary>
        <p class="search">48314b4e58343498</p>
        <p class="search">4f32353857383498</p>
        <p class="search">4f58585959343498</p>
        <p class="search">56365a5959343498</p>
      </details>
    </p></details
  >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your question is, but if you want to get every element you can do that in JS via the `document.getElementsByClassName` method. This would be an example use:

```js
classes = document.getElementsByClassName("search");

for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML += classes[i].innerText +"<br>"
}
```

```html
<div id="details-info">
  <details>
    <summary><a href="#" class="search">SD</a></summary>
        <p>
          <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
            <summary class="search">172.17.42.26 </summary>
                <p class="search">3033343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">3038373857383498</p>
                <p class="search">3647595959343498</p>
                <p class="search">374d343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">4253595959343498</p>
                <p class="search">4758343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">5139343857383498</p>
                <p class="search">5837553546353498</p>                  </details>
         </p>
         <p>
         <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
              <summary class="search">172.17.42.24 </summary>                   <p class="search">5336594e58343498</p>
                  <p class="search">56344f4330393498</p>
                  <p class="search">5a4a444133393498</p>              </details>
         </p>
   </details>
   <details>
      <summary><a href="#" class="search">HinduKush</a></summary>
      <p>
        <details style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;">
          <summary class="search">172.17.42.25 </summary>
          <p class="search">48314b4e58343498</p>
          <p class="search">4f32353857383498</p>
          <p class="search">4f58585959343498</p>
          <p class="search">56365a5959343498</p>
          </details></p></details>
          <p id="search-result"></p>
</div>
```

This is how you would get all the elements you mentioned.